# Is it possible to re-position a position:absolute DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, css-position

The scenario:-

A published HTML page has position:absolute DIVs and all DIV heights are set to specific px values. The page is editable via an online CMS such as Surreal or Cushy. The editor enters more content that the DIV was designed to take. The result is that the extra content overflows the DIV and the page design is trashed.

Is there any way that when an editor does this that the DIV height expands AND all other DIVs on the page move down? Bare in mind that the DIV heights cannot be set to 100% but have fixed px values.

I am assuming the solution maybe jQuery or JavaScript - any ideas?

```
<body>
```

```
 <div id="two" style="position:absolute;left:163px;top:0px;width:738px;height:269px;z-index:5;padding:0;">
      <img src="images/two.jpg" id="two" alt="two" border="0" title="two" style="width:738px;height:269px;">
 </div>

 <div id="three" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:350px;width:900px;height:294px;z-index:6;" class="editable">
 <!-- div content -->
 <!-- this is where the user/editor will add content -->
 </div>

 <div id="four" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:900px;height:323px;z-index:7;padding:0;">
 <div id="five" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:162px;height:269px;z-index:0;padding:0;">
      <a href="./../apage.html"><img src="logo.gif" id="logo" alt="Logo" border="0" title="Logo" style="width:162px;height:269px;"></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: without seeing the layout of the site it's not really easy to say.  It depends on whether or not you can wrap the element that's causing the problem in a relative positioned element and whether or not that would break your site

Comment: It also depends on if you have other absolutely positioned elements. That will start to be tough. No offense meant but, in general, there is almost always a better way than position:absolute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see exactly the scenario, but have you considered the scroll within your fixed size divs ?

Give a class to those divs, such as

```
<div class="bescrollable"></div>
```

and then in your css :

```
.bescrollable {overflow:auto;}
```

scrollbars will be added when overflows occur

Answer (score 1):

You can set height of the div according to the content like this:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;   
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}

<div class="container">
     <div class="content">...</div>
</div>

$('.container').css('height', $('.content').height());
```

Here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kdktw/

As CBRRacer mentioned in the comments, if we could see the HTML, the answer would be more accurate to your situation.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This would be predicated on the height of the content within the box. Probably the best method would be to have the height of the content div set to auto and use javascript to get the height of the element.

```
// Using jQuery
var contentDivHeight = $('#myContentDiv').height();
var startingOffset = 250;    // The height of the div original set at startup
```

Then you could simply add this height to each of the primary display controls that would have to be moved "down". If you assigned them all a common class they could all easily be selected (such "primaryInterface" or something).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.primaryInterface')each(function (i) {
        var newTop = this.offset().top + contentDivHeight - startingOffset;
        var newLeft = this.offset().left;
        this.offset({ top: newTop, left: newleft });
    });
});
```

This code is untested, but ideally, once the page loads, it would find all of the elements with the specified class and set their top offset to be the difference between the starting height of the div and the resultant height.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. And apologies - I've been out of action for quite a while.

OK, I don't think I explained myself very well. Typical page added to OP and the problem lies with the DIV ID called "FooterLayer". If the user adds more content in DIV "three" I need the footerlayer to move.

Comment: So the top:700px needs to reflect the new content that got added to div "three"